# Hebrew texts (like the Torah) with IPA (International Phonetic Alphabet) transliteration of each term?

Tags: words, torah-study, pronunciation

Is there a mapping of Hebrew terms in the Torah (or any other key Hebrew text like you'd find on Sefaria), to the [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) pronunciation? Ideally even there would be at least two transliterations, one to Modern Hebrew pronunciations, and one to Biblical Hebrew pronunciations. In my search I found https://github.com/openscriptures/HebrewLexicon, which is based on Strong's Hebrew Dictionary, and some other stuff I am not familiar with. But perhaps that is enough to map any word in the Torah to a pronunciation (and even a definition)? If not, what are the free/open sources I can use to map each word in the Torah or other books to the IPA pronunciation.

I saw something like [this](https://www.shalomhaverim.org/English/bereshit_english_8.htm), but that transliteration scheme is custom or otherwise not using the IPA system. Ideally it would follow one of the standards, ideally IPA, but any other "standard" [romanization scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Hebrew) that accurately captures the pronunciation would be suitable.

Ideally too, it would take the niqqud/diacritic form of the word and give the IPA, or even without niqqud. But something with any of the discussed features would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unaware of any IPA mapping of an entire text. I believe if you look up each of the 22 Hebrew letters, along with their Aramaic and Arabic Cognates, you will find IPA listed for each letter. Please note that there is disagreements on what IPA sound matches to each letter. For example, many scholars believe there are two distinct IPA sounds for Ayin.

But also keep in mind some hebrew letters will have two distinct IPA sounds depending on whether that letter has a dagesh or not. These letters would be Bet, Gimmel, Dalet, Kaf, Pei, and Tau.